# Find Duplicate item in array php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a problem with one of the jobs I'm following:
I have an array structured like this:

```
$prodottocar=array( 
                                            
    'CodicArt'=>$_POST['codart'],
    'NomeProdotto'=>$_POST['nomeprodotto'],
    'Categoria'=>$_POST['categoria'],
    'Colore'=>$_POST['colore'],
    'Prezzo'=>$_POST['prezzo'],
    'Taglia'=>$taglia['Taglia'],
    'Quantita'=>$_POST[$quantita]
                                                
);
```

this array will then be pushed into a session array to this i have to check if there is another one with same codiceart and Taglia inside so as to tell me if it is duplicated,
i tried like this:

```
if($prodottocar['CodicArt'] != NULL ){
    if(in_array($_POST['codart'], array_column($_SESSION['carrello'], 'CodicArt')) and in_array($taglia['Taglia'], array_column($_SESSION['carrello'], 'Taglia')))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Articolo duplicato");</script>';                                                                                 
     }else
     {                                                                       
       array_push($_SESSION['carrello'], $prodottocar);                                                                          
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Prodotto inserito");</script>';
                                                                             
     }
}
```

but inserted the first article when I go to insert another article with a different heart code, he detects that the same size is already inserted for that article, as if the logical AND operator does not weigh him
some idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will need a fast way to check/match something, it is always a smart idea to put that as an array key (which is a HashMap undercover).

Since you need two parameters to match, I would generate a key from both parameters:

```php
$key = sprintf('%s|%s', $_POST['codart'], $taglia['Taglia']);
```

Then when storing, put the whole data under this key:

```php
$_SESSION['carrello'][$key] = $prodottocar;
```

And the check is also quick and easy then:

```php
array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['carrello'])
```

The problem in your solution is that you are checking each column separately, so you may get false-positives when there is one product with the searched codart and another item with searched Taglia value.

Comment: So i need to do a if(array_key_exists($key,$_SESSION['carrello']){ /*duplicate}else{ /*insertinto*/} ?

Comment: so i miss to say, my work insert into array a multiple time i've a form with a to value like the number of Taglia in one time the user insert the value like "35->1, 36->2" the first i check is work but when check the second say me a false-positive

Comment: Yes, you are right about the duplicate vs insertinto positions.
As for your second comment, sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to say. Could you please add a full example to your question with data which you are using/passing and at which point the expected result doesn't match the actual result.

Comment: So i explain better
GUI: User select from a list of Articles one of them next he click on "Taglia" (is a size of shoes,pants,shirt) and show a tables with multiple size with multiple input "one for each size" then they click add now i've do a loop to find what size are empty  or not then if is not empty i pick it and insert into $prodottocar next to $_session['carrello'] every check i do that, now my problem is when i check duplicate so i've $_SESSION['carrello'] is a multidimensional array ($_SESSION['carrello'] ->array->key) i  need to check if the cod of item and size of it already in

Comment: I am more interested in your test data than in your GUI. The only example of data I've seen so far is "35->1, 36->2" (which I take is [codart]->[Taglia]). I think this example should work even with your implementation, because 35 and 36 are unique values and 1 and 2 are unique values. The false positives would start if you then added a third item "35->2" - which is unique, but the condition would say it's duplicate (because it can find "35" in codart column, and can find "2" in Taglia column).
Anyway, have you tried my suggestion with the array key? Does it work for you?